# XCUITest throwing SIGKILL and is generally unstable

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I've tried to use XCUITest framework to set up some UI tests of the iOS app. I was able to write some basic tests, but I've encountered the problem.

The framework is acting highly unstable. One time, I get all my tests passed as expected, but if I run tests right after it, without any code change, some tests would fail, while some would still pass. This seems related not to the app state itself, but to Xcode's state. Other time, every test is stopped by `SIGKILL` signal and it is required to tap "play" button to run next test. Complete clean, removing app from the device and restarting Xcode sometimes helps.

Using the app manually is perfect, no crashes or other failures.

Am I doing something wrong? The framework seems to be great, but it is not usable for me now.

I'm using the latest Xcode 7.3 with device on iOS 9.3.

I've also tried KIF framework and the issues are approximately the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am running on KIF, so, I am not sure this will apply to UITesting.

Oddly enough, you need to change your target's type from ui-testing to unit-test, and this works fine for me afterwards.

The bad news is, there's no way to do this from XCode, so, you will need to do this by hand in the pbxproj.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I've checked it - changing `productType` to `unit-test` stops the project from building with `Application was not verified` error. Also, KIF target has `unit-test` by default, while still having these runtime test errors...

Comment: Hmmm... the Application was not verified error was new. I didn't see that on mine. I am sorry, I am not sure what went wrong.